# Existence of a nonmeasurable set with slices of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exist a nonmeasurable set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for each line $l$ in the plane the intersection $A\cap l$ has one dimensional measure zero.

(What about the problem for only horizontal and vertical lines?)

Obviously if $A$ is measurable its measure must be zero, because of Fubini's theorem!

Comment: [Example 10.21](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA142&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis* gives an example of a nonmeasurable plane set having at most two points in common with any line.